# CSS for different layers P5.js

Tags: javascript, flexbox, p5.js

`canvas.style('z-index', '-1');`  doesn't work with noscrollbars.css and broke p5.easycam.js in chrome.
I'm trying to get rid of scrollbars on a full window canvas. this works really well in Firefox but breaks p5.easycam.js in chrome, I get no errors in console. maybe it has something to do with node.js?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="noscrollbars.css">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="p5.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.easycam.min.js"></script>
  </head>  <body>  <main> </main> </body>
</html>
```

noscrollbars.css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

myscript.js  (credit Paul Wheeler for pointing out question error)

```
var canvas;

var easycam;
let CamState = { distance: 2000, center: [0,0,0], rotation: [1,0,0,0]};

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  canvas.position(0, 0);
  canvas.style('z-index', '-1');

  fill(255, 64, 0);

  easycam = createEasyCam();
  easycam.setViewport([0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight]);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  ambientLight(100, 100, 100);
  pointLight(255, 255, 255, -100, -100, 100);
  directionalLight(100, 100, 100, -1, 0.1, 0.8);
  box(150);
}
```

I did not know before posting but I'm guessing multiple canvas layers (in chrome) don't correspond to the css I wrote and I need to go learn more about that as `canvas.style('z-index', '0');` works

Comment: it was canvas.style('z-index', '-1'); in mysketch.js that breaks it, ill edit the question to reflect that when I figure some more things out

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Runnable example:

```js
let easycam;

function setup() {
  let c = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  c.style('z-index', '-1');
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 64, 0);

  easycam = createEasyCam();
  easycam.setViewport([0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight]);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  ambientLight(100, 100, 100);
  pointLight(255, 255, 255, -100, -100, 100);
  directionalLight(100, 100, 100, -1, 0.1, 0.8);
  box(150);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test-link-before-head.css">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://freshfork.github.io/p5.EasyCam/p5.easycam.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main> </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One thing that is implicitly different in my example than yours (because of how Stack Snippets work) is that the script tag for the sketch JS will be at the end of the `<body>` in my example, but it is in the head in yours. However so long as your `myscript.js` just declares global functions and doesn't run any code that assumes EasyCam has been loaded before p5.js calls your `setup()` function then it should be fine. I tested this explicitly with this sketch: https://editor.p5js.org/Kumu-Paul/sketches/P1jaLwJ5D which also works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have tried more sketches. it was canvas.style('z-index', '-1'); in mysketch.js that breaks it, ill edit the question to reflect that

Comment: Hmm, it still works fine for me with the `z-index` of -1, perhaps you have some other CSS or HTML that causes some other element to be atop the canvas when it has this z-index, or maybe you're using a different version of EasyCam?

Comment: most recent easycam, my css and html are verbatim from my question. what browser? it works great for me in firefox but not chrome

Comment: Huh, Chrome 96 on Mac OS 10.15 here.